# stack level too deep how do I even start to debug this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea

Oh boy, I'm not even sure if you can help me.

I've got a very old app I've upgraded to Rails 3.1 from Rails 2.3.14 (as I said very old. Also, I know 6.x is current but I need to go one step at a time with this)

Note: ruby 1.9.3-p551

I could get the default "welcome to rails" page working....but when I removed it and ran rails again...I get...

```
SystemStackError at /

stack level too deep
```

I have no idea where to begin with this error.

This is all I get from the command line output...

```
$ rails s -p 4000 -b 0.0.0.0
/home/fonso/app-dev/vendor/soap4r/xsd/iconvcharset.rb:9:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/home/fonso/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/12_hour_time-0.0.4/lib/12_hour_time/action_view_helpers.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant POSITION
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:4000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2021-07-10 10:57:36] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2021-07-10 10:57:36] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2021-07-10 10:57:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=15150 port=4000


Started GET "/" for 99.123.48.212 at 2021-07-10 10:57:43 -0700
  Processing by SidebarLinksController#homepage_index as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
  (gem) activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `'


Started POST "/__better_errors/40609660/variables" for 99.123.48.212 at 2021-07-10 10:57:44 -0700
```

So my question is...how do I even begin to debug this?

Note: I have intellij and I can set break points it's just...where do I even begin?

Note 2: I've found something that "might" help me [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/bendilley/1453a555e981ed533f68) but I'm a little confused as to how I could implement it here. How would I run this against my app in this situation?

UPDATE: (added per request of commenter below)
homepage_index is just this...

```
 def homepage_index
    render :action => 'index'
  end
```

...and the referenced "index" code is this...

```
<h1 class="welcome">Welcome to the Database</h1>

<% if session[:unauthorized_error] %>
  <span class="error">You have insufficient privileges to access that!</span>
  <% if !logged_in? %>
    <br />
    Please log in:
    <%= render :partial => 'sessions/form' %>
    <br/>
    <br/>
  <% else %>
    <% session[:unauthorized_error] = false %>
    <% session[:unauthorized_params] = nil %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if session[:account_message] %>
  <span class="error"><%= session[:account_message].gsub("\n", "<br />") %></span>
  <% session[:account_message] = false %>
<% end %>

<% if session[:logout_message] %>
  <span class="info">You have been logged out!</span>
  <% session[:logout_message] = false %>
<% end %>

<%= do_jsalert %>

<p class="welcome">This is the release <%= DB_VERSION %>. Please
  report any problems you find. You will need authorization to do much
  more than get reports; please talk to a staff member to acquire the
  necessary account.</p>
```

Comment: What's in `SidebarLinksController#homepage_index`?

Comment: @SebastianPalma added info in the "Update" area

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to go piece by piece checking where's the `SystemStackError`. As per the gist code, that can be added as a single file in your config/initializers/ folder. After restarting your app, those changes will take effect.

Comment: @SebastianPalma I've got the code in config/initializers but I do not understand how to run it against my code in my case.

Comment: Here  I'm just guessing. But maybe you could try opening the rails console, and using `app.get(...)` to emulate a HTTP request, but from the console itself. Try the very same `/` route. `app.get("/")`

Comment: To debug this I would start by commenting all the code related to that action and then start adding code until the error appears, that way you can narrow it down to some code. I think it's also important if you can show the code of the index action and also try render a `homepage_index.html` file instead of rendering the index action.